# Python Encryption - How do I get same encrypted value if I encrypt the same message

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, encryption

I have been using a python library Fernet and using it to encrypt the emails. My problem is if I encrypt the same email again it gives a different token.

Is there a way, or alternate library which would give me the same output if the input(email in my case) remains the same?

I can't use hashing because we need to decrypt emails later.

this is what I am doing currently. We need to get the same token twice because before inserting a new email into the system I need to check its uniqueness. Alternate would be to decrypt all emails first which doesn't looks like ideal.

```
f = Fernet(key)
token = f.encrypt(b"xyz@asdfljlsdafjsdalkfj.com")
token
```

Comment: you might want to show the code snippet, that you use for encryption.

You might also explain why it is important to get the same token twice.

Both infos might help to provide you with an answer, that can help to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @gelonida I did the updates as you suggested.

Comment: Randomness is an important element in cryptography so all "good" encryption algorithms use a random element. To keep your security level high I would recommend hashing your emails and save the hash **in addition** to your encrypted data. The only other option would be to use the ECB mode of AES but this is **highly discouraged**

Comment: @MichaelFehr I think this scenario warrants one of the few cases the use of ECB mode or even CBC mode with a static IV. An authenticated mode also doesn't seem to be necessary because the data is stored and probably never sent directly somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the specified usage (storing the ciphertext within a secured server space, the ciphertext never leaves the server in encrypted form) the usage of AES in mode **ECB** could be an option (thanks to @Artjom B.).

As the ECB mode does not have any random element (except the key) you get the same [plaintext - key - ciphertext] combination for each run - you can test the encryption with my live example code: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/SoPythonAesEcb256StringEncryption.

This is the output:

```
AES ECB 256 String encryption with fixed key
plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
encryptionKey (Base64): UFmBQEE4MpP4m9btYFlUmEqRE3g5wa2Yfa2T28uB+OU=

* * * Encryption * * *
ciphertext: fp6Qqo3zzznH7Hs9c0q4Q+GDRjzhUcatkl/vbTMim2e/5HUQgZLUmsg7uMcNmQhZ

* * * Decryption * * *
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

To run the code you need to use the external library **Pycryptodome**, available here: https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/ and the documentation here: https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html

**Security warning** The following code uses the AES algorithm in mode **ECB** that is **UNSECURE** in most cases!

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
import base64

def base64Encoding(input):
  dataBase64 = base64.b64encode(input)
  dataBase64P = dataBase64.decode("UTF-8")
  return dataBase64P

def base64Decoding(input):
    return base64.decodebytes(input.encode("ascii"))

def aesEcbEncryptToBase64(encryptionKey, plaintext):
  cipher = AES.new(encryptionKey, AES.MODE_ECB)
  ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext.encode("ascii"), AES.block_size))
  return base64Encoding(ciphertext)

def aesEcbDecryptFromBase64(decryptionKey, ciphertextDecryptionBase64):
  ciphertext = base64Decoding(ciphertextDecryptionBase64)
  cipher = AES.new(decryptionKey, AES.MODE_ECB)
  decryptedtext = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ciphertext), AES.block_size)
  decryptedtextP = decryptedtext.decode("UTF-8")
  return decryptedtextP
  
print("AES ECB 256 String encryption with fixed key")

plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
print("plaintext: " + plaintext)

encryptionKeyBase64 = "UFmBQEE4MpP4m9btYFlUmEqRE3g5wa2Yfa2T28uB+OU="
encryptionKey = base64Decoding(encryptionKeyBase64)
print("encryptionKey (Base64): " + encryptionKeyBase64)

print("\n* * * Encryption * * *") 
ciphertextBase64 = aesEcbEncryptToBase64(encryptionKey, plaintext)
print("ciphertext: " + ciphertextBase64)

print("\n* * * Decryption * * *") 
decryptedtext = aesEcbDecryptFromBase64(encryptionKey, ciphertextBase64)
print("plaintext:  " + decryptedtext)
```